# Copy data to another field at insert execution

Tags: php, mysql, post, insert, copy

I need to copy the data inside a field to another field.  I need to copy "reg" to "reg_copy" when I insert record.  Is there a way to do this inside my script?

```
<?
$order = "INSERT INTO reg_add ( 
connect_date, 
reg, 
reg_copy,
first_name, 
last_name)

VALUES

('$_POST[connect_date]', 
'$_POST[reg]',
'$_POST[reg_copy]',
'$_POST[first_name]', 
'$_POST[last_name]')";

$result = mysql_query($order);

if ($result) {

$reg =      $_REQUEST['reg'] ;
$first_name =   $_REQUEST['first_name'];

header("location: reg_add_success.php?reg=" . urlencode($reg) . "&first_name=" . urlencode($first_name));
}
else {
header("location: reg_add_fail.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Please read: http://bobby-tables.com/ and http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php, paying attention to the syntax for using associative array values inside strings. Please also explain what you mean by wanting to "copy" the values - copy them to/from where?

Comment: why can't you use $_POST[reg] for the insert?

Comment: why not just insert `$_POST[reg]` twice ? and please read up about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: I don't get it. Do you want that reg and reg_copy are the same value?

Comment: I need to copy the data to a different field.  I can't use the same name.

Comment: I need to have two different fields (reg and reg_orig) with the same data.  But my client only keys in the input for reg.

Comment: Sometimes its hard to put it in words what you want to ask.  Thanks everyone!  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yah, just use:

```
$order = "INSERT INTO reg_add set 
`connect_date` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[connect_date])."',
`reg` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[reg])."',
`reg_copy` = `reg`,
`first_name` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[first_name])."',
`last_name` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[last_name])."';
```

or maybe i understand your question wrong ? :/ provide more information then.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this?

```
('$_POST[connect_date]', 
'$_POST[reg]',
'$_POST[reg]',
'$_POST[first_name]', 
'$_POST[last_name]')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should be more clear in your question, i'm not 100% sure what you mean but from reading your question its looks like you want to do this:

```
<?
$order = "INSERT INTO reg_add ( 
connect_date, 
reg, 
reg_copy,
first_name, 
last_name
) VALUES ("
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[connect_date])"', 
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[reg])."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[reg])."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[first_name])."', 
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[last_name])."'
")";

/* Always use mysql_real_escape_string on your POST and GET */

$result = mysql_query($order);

if ($result) {

$reg =      $_REQUEST['reg'] ;
$first_name =   $_REQUEST['first_name'];

header("location: reg_add_success.php?reg=" . urlencode($reg) . "&first_name=" .     urlencode($first_name));
}
else {
header("location: reg_add_fail.php");
}
?>
```